# Facebook realtime updates for page contain invalid post id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I've set up a subscription so that my app receives realtime updates for a specific page. This works as expected, and I'm receiving updates when a user posts to the page.

The update only contains the page id, so I then use the Graph API to get the details of the post. The problem is that the post id in the realtime update isn't valid and I get an error from Graph API.

If I query the page's feed, the post shows up there with a different (correct) id.

The correct id consists of <page id>_<post id>. The one in the realtime update is just the <post id> without the prefixed page id.

The data in the realtime update:

```
{
"object":"page",
"entry":[{
  "id":"<page id>",
  "time":1372177485,
  "changes":[{
    "field":"feed",
    "value": {"item":"post", "verb":"add", "post_id":<post id>}
  }]
}]
}
```

The Graph query:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<post id>
```

Response:

```
(GraphMethodException - #100) Unsupported get request.
```

The Graph query is being performed using a long-lived (non-expiring) page token. I get the same response using the Graph API Explorer tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) and also when using a short-lived user token.

Obviously I could simply prepend the page id onto the given page id to generate a valid id, but that's not very robust, should the format change at any time. Why isn't Facebook returning valid ids? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: File a bug with Facebook.

Comment: Found an existing bug that, in conjunction with the bug that is marked as a dupe of it, covers my issues.
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/595764950453041